# How to derive WZW model’s energy-momentum tensor? The result is of course the Sugawara construction

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, wess-zumino-witten, affine-lie-algebra

I want to know how to derive WZW’s energy-momentum tensor. We know WZW action is
$$
S_{WZW}[g]=\frac{k}{16\pi}\int d^2x Tr(\partial g^{-1}\partial g) - \frac{ik}{24\pi}
\int_B d^3y \epsilon_{abc} Tr(h^{-1}\partial^a h h^{-1}\partial^b h h^{-1}\partial^c h).
$$
Can we derive the energy-momentum tensor $T(z, \bar{z})$ from above action by
$$
T(z)=\frac{\delta S}{\delta g(z)}
$$

I’m interested in the motivation behind Sugawara construction:
$$
T(z) = \frac{1}{2(k+g)}\sum_a (J^aJ^a)(z)
$$
where $J(z)$ is the current which modes satisfy the affine Lie algebra relation
$$
[J^a_n, J^b_m]=\sum_c if^{abc}J^c_{n+m}+ kn\delta_{ab} \delta_{n+m, 0}
$$
One can of course verify the Virasoro relation by computing the Lie bracket and using affine relation. But the motivation of Sugawara may lie in the derivation from WZW action and taking functional derivative with respect to the field $g$.

But I find it difficult when computing that. It is an exercise in the Big Yellow Book, page 624, 669, Ex15.1